# Moment js is not displaying error message for days after tomorrow

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to display error message if date is after tomorrow. It means, if today is 05 Oct, then the error message should be displayed for days after 06 Oct (and not for 06).

The weird thing is because this is not working only in morning.

```
const validateDays = (attr, data) => { 
const [date] = data[attr];

const futureDay = moment().add(1, 'days');

if (date.isAfter(futureDay)) {
    return "The error message";
  }

}
```

Comment: `date` is string and string has no method `isAfter`. It would be better if you provide a more precise example

Comment: Your date variable is not a moment instance or a date.

Comment: I updated my code. so date is well, and is getting today date. seems the issue is with isAfter method

Comment: What's the content and type of `date` inside the function? Could you provide a `console.log` of that?

Comment: @DavidBuzatu
```
_d: Wed Oct 07 2020 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
__proto__: Object
_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"
_i: "2020-10-05T00:00:00"
```

Comment: @alar so `date` is for sure a `moment` instance of a date?

Comment: @DavidBuzatu yes, 
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2020-10-05T00:00:00", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
_d: Wed Oct 07 2020 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) {}
_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"
_i: "2020-10-05T00:00:00"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, by changing

```
const futureDay = moment().add(1, 'days');
```

to

```
const futureDay = moment().endOf('day').add(1, 'days');;
```